# Operators in PIG Latin

Tags: operators, apache-pig, latin

I have two values in a PIG Latin script, what should I do to use them mathematically, like if I had two variables

```
A=(5)
B=(4)
```

How can I do A+B or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Foreach stmt to do any mathematical operation, please see the below sample example.

**input.txt**

```
2,1
5,3
7,5
```

**Pigscript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (val1:int , val1:int); 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (val1+val2) AS sum, (val1-val2) AS diff;
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(3,1)
(8,2)
(12,2)
```

Comment: but the are just two Variables, each one having is a tuple of one element, can I just create new tuple on the fly without loading any new input file from the filesystem ?

Comment: Can you paste your pigscript in the question part?. please update some sample inputs and also mention what is your desired output. i will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can able to do any arithmetic operation in it but the thing is that any variable declaration is kind of different in pig latin -

what you have to do is -

> % declare A 5 % declare B 4

and in any of the foreach statement you can use

> dummy = foreach column-1,...., column-n, **A+B as summation;**

this would work.

```
Let me know if I fulfilled you need.
```